# toplink migration installer The system cannot find path specified

Tags: eclipselink, toplink

I have to migrate Toplink 11g to Toplink 12.1.3. I downloaded Toplink migration installer as per instructions and try to ran command.

1. I ran from the directory where i installed. C:\Toplink\toplink\utils\rename>
2. I have workspace called 'weblogicmigration' which has toplink packages, on which i want to run migration installer.

My command:  packageRename C:/workspace/WeblogicMigration c:/test

But it is giving following error about system path.

C:\Toplink\toplink\utils\rename>~1\bin\java -Xmx256M -classpath C:\Toplink\topli
nk\utils\rename\package-rename.jar org.eclipse.persistence.utils.rename.MigrateT
opLinkToEclipseLink C:\WORKSP~1\WEBLOG~1 c:\Test C:\Toplink\toplink\utils\rename
\package-rename.properties
The system cannot find the path specified.

I tried this with toplink 12.1.3 and EclipseLink exe files, but same issue. Please help.

Comment: ~1\bin\java is that what you are actually using in windows? just make that java, make sure java.exe is in PATH

Comment: also there is packageRenameEclipseLink.cmd in that dir :) - I thought toplink 11g had eclipselink, are you sure you need to run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires that properties file

https://github.com/suman-ganta/hotjobs/blob/master/hotjobs/external/eclipselink/utils/rename/package-rename.properties

to rule out typos, type full path to java.exe, folders etc and use " " to wrap directories with spaces

make sure you have JAVA_HOME set

Comment: Yes,package-rename.properties is available in the directory from where i am running this execution. It came from installation. It is in this directory "C:\Toplink\toplink\utils\rename". But still getting error. Do i need to set any path for this installer ?

Comment: sorry iam new to toplink. I have set java class path in my windows 7. For example, if i want to run this package C:\workspace\WeblogicMigration\src\com\sync\util, what could be the syntax ?

Comment: first describe what are you trying to do and why

Comment: I want to migrate native toplink 11g to toplink 12.1.3 as per this link   http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/migrnativetoplink.htm#BCGDDHBC.   I have my source code which has toplink files. I installed toplink migration installer as per link and try to ran installer which renames native toplink packages to newer version.  When doing this , i am getting error.

Comment: are you literally using ~1\bin\java in windows?

Comment: Plz see my java env settings. Path: ;C:\Tools\Java7\bin;  Classpath:;C:\Tools\Java7\lib

Comment: do you have JAVA_HOME set?

Comment: great. This works now after setting Java_home. Thanks for your time and solving this issue. Kudos. But i wonder, whats special of  JAVA_HOME here, i have path and classpath in place and every other java stuff works fine except this.